# ImageLists in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I need to load several images from a database which of course takes some time.
In .NET, I would load them only once, then save them all together as an "ImageList".

Unfortunately, when I type "ImageList", it isn't recognized in a portable Xamarin project.

Did I just not find it, or does it have a different name, or does it simply not exists yet for Xamarin projects?

Thank you!

Comment: ImageList is a WinForms control.  In Xamarin Forms you would use a ListView of ImageCells

Comment: @Jason Could I save this to a file to speed up loading it later on?

Comment: Yes you could do that